# ECC check for Erased pages in NAND

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wanted to verify the following patch

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8368341/

For same , wrote all zero's to one of nand partition :

nandwrite -n /dev/mdt1 < /dev/zero

But now when I dump this nand partition, see following errors:

```
 ECC: 3 uncorrectable bitflip(s) at offset 0x00000000
 ECC: 2 uncorrectable bitflip(s) at offset 0x00000800
 ECC: 2 uncorrectable bitflip(s) at offset 0x00001000
```

I thought above mentioned patch , suppose to fix this ECC errors but
it didn't.

Is they other way to verify this patch ?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: But its related to Linux kernel patch ?

Comment: Unless you're actually writing or modifying code for this patch then it's not really a programming question ?

Comment: But after applying this patch to kernel code base, issue is still seen, shouldn't this related to programming?

Comment: If you're not actually doing any programming then no, it's not a programming question. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your procedure does not test the patch.  Since you wrote data, the NAND partition is no longer in an erased state.  So the conditions don't match the patch.

Comment: But if you see, Author of this patch suggests that he uses nandwrite --noecc to verify this patch